# how change secured-="true" in identity.xml?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I want to change secured= true in following lines in identity.xml:

```
<Resource context="(.*)/authenticationendpoint(.*)" secured="false" http-method="all"/>
```

I added the following codes in deployment.toml, then restart WSO2 IS

```
[resource.access_control]
 context="(.*)/authenticationendpoint(.*)" 
  secured="true" 
  http-method="all"
```

But, the result is FAIL.

Could you tell me what code I need add in deployment.toml ?

Thanks

henry

Answer (score 1):

You can change a configuration via deployment.toml, only  ifthat config is templated in the particular .j2 file.

If you go to
`<IS-HOME>/repository/resources/conf/templates/repository/conf/identity/identity.xml.j2` file and check the line

```
<Resource context="(.*)/authenticationendpoint(.*)" secured="false" http-method="all"/>
```

it is hardcoded in the .j2 file also. So you won't be able to set secured="true" in this line by adding a config to deployment.toml.
The change can be only done by changing identity.xmlj2 file.

Also, note that it's not recommended to change the .j2 file if the configs are not templated, because it is the default behavior and only deployment.toml config will be looked at as the config changes.

An alternative option is:

Apply resource control access to the deployment.toml with  different context which matches to the API path(not exact the context="(.*)/authenticationendpoint(.*)" but with a regex matching to the endpoint) under `[[resource.access_control]]`. The added config will reflect in identity.xml file at the beginning of the resource access controls. The first context match is applicable for a endpoint access control.